# Add variables in designer for NativeActivity<T> in wf4

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have a class extending NativeActivity

I want to allow adding variables to the scope of the activity from the designer. How can I modify the code of my activity so the designer will let me add variables?

[image: No option to add variables in custom activity through designer]

My code

```
public class MyActivity : NativeActivity<bool>
{
    public InArgument<string> SomeInArg { get; set; }

    public InArgument<object> RefInArg { get; set; }

    public WorkflowDataContext Data { get; set; }

    public Collection<Variable> Variables { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        Result.Set(context, true);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Surprising enough, adding a getter which returns an empty collection - solves the problem. I suspect that the designer tries to somehow access the `variables` collection and when null is returned - it gives no option to set variables in the designer.

```
    public Collection<Variable> Variables { get; } = new Collection<Variable>();
```

But now an attempt to access the variables results in

```
Activity '1.1: MyActivity' cannot access this variable 
because it is declared at the scope of activity '1.1: MyActivity'.  
An activity can only access its own implementation variables.
```

Comment: Maybe you should initialize your collection in the contructor to avoid a "new" each time you get the property.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Collection<Variable> variables;
public Collection<Variable> Variables
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.variables == null)
            {
                this.variables = new Collection<Variable>();

            }
            return this.variables;
        }
    }
```

This will initalize your collection only once avoiding the "access" issue.

Comment: Yep, thanks to your comment before, i did. See the update of my own answer. It works and lets me add variables via the designer, but gets me a new error while attempting to read them (not because collection null). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616844/wf4-an-activity-can-only-access-its-own-implementation-variables